# CSS, relative font size

Tags: css, fonts

Is it possible to set a font size to a percentage of the container size?  I have a list of items which have an image, a header and a description.  The image resizes automatically as the user resizes the window.  I would like the header font to do the same.

**edit: Javascript/JQuery is fine.**

Comment: By container size, do you mean including the padding, including the padding and border, or including the padding, border, and margin?

Comment: Also, IMO, I discourage you of resizing the font size based on the viewport/window size. It prevents readability majorly.

Comment: container, window, padding, whatever.  I just want it to be able to be resized automatically relative to anything else that changes when the window, and thus the layout, is resized...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to expand on Tyler's answer, this is what javascript is meant for, though I'm tad sure you can achieve the same feat using CSS3 viewports, you will be better off using jQuery (it's *usually* in the cache of most browser's and *always* hosted on Google so no need to worry :)

If you have a css like this:

```
#body #mytext {
   font-size: 50%;
}
```

you can dynamically resize in jQuery like this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('#body #mytext').css('font-size',($(window).width()*0.5)+'px');
});
```

Comment: Just an FYI, you don't have to specify that `#mytext` is a descendant of `#body` unless you are trying to increase the specificity value (which quite frankly is the wrong way to go if you are using id's).

Comment: It depends on the scenario, there's nothing wrong about using CSS in this way. Albeit, it's just a demo...

Comment: Well, [each value in an `id` attribute must be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/global-attributes.html#the-id-attribute). Therefore, `#mytext` can only refer to one element at most. With that said, there is not much need to specify any of its ascendants in the CSS rule.

Comment: Oh my, just got what you were actually trying to explain. Yes indeed, but I was just providing an example :)

Comment: I couldn't get this to work on jsfiddle but I'll take your word for it :)

Answer (score 11):

In CSS3, there is the `vw` unit, which stands for 1/100 of the viewport width. For example,

```
h1 { font-size: 5.5vw; }
```

sets the heading font size to 5.5% of the viewport width.

However, this seems to work on IE 9 (Standards Mode) only so far. Moreover, IE 9 does not dynamically change the value of the unit when the browser window is resized, only on reload.

Comment: This isn't relative the container's size, though.

Comment: This gives the same effect, but any changes to the size of the container whether it be by JavaScript or by changing the CSS, this will not work quite right. One would have to remember to update this upon changing the size of the container.

Answer (score 3):

No, this can only be done in JavaScript.

Comment: just as Tyler said, fonts are calculated in relation to the current set fontsize of the browser, if you use dynamic font sizes like "em" or "%" values. You have to calculate the font size with javascript if you want to get a size depending on a tag's height / width

Answer (score 1):

Is jquery is an option?

Super easy if it is: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yhRvr/1/)

```
<div id="container">
    <p>HELLO WORLD!</p>
</div>​


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sizeMe = ($('#container').height() / 100) * 90; /* 90% of container */
    $('p').css('font-size', sizeMe);
};
</script>
```

Comment: There are many other attributes that would theoretically need to be changed (i.e. text-indent, line-height, etc.).

Comment: But then again, the OP didn't ask about that. :)

Comment: That's because he/she didn't put the JS in the onresize handler. If you put it in there, it should work.

Answer (score -1):

I've done it with jquery in the past. Check out this article if it's of any interest to you. You can also use CSS to detect device width (not browser, and it's not supported in older browsers).

http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/